# Clean up or repair Mac OSX bootloader?

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot-camp, bootloader

I have Windows 7 Home Premium installed in a Bootcamp partition on my iMac. A couple of months ago, I restored an image of my harddrive, which I've done multiple times before with success, but on PC's. It restored the image successfully, and windows worked, however when starting up my machine, it hangs at either the grey screen where you hear the gong, or it hangs at a black screen with a flashing cursor.

Thinking it was that version of Windows, I tried going into Bootcamp through Mac, removing the Windows partition and starting again from the ground up. It didn't fix the booting issue. It doesn't appear to be an issue with Windows to me, as we've had it working fine in the past, and also once windows starts, there's no problems to be seen.

It's been getting a little worse as time goes on, and this morning it took almost 10 restarts to successfully start into Windows. It starts into Mac just fine when told to, but really doesn't like windows anymore. I'm wondering if there's a chance it's something sitting inside the Mac OSX bootloader (Darwin, if I'm correct?) I've looked up on Google and on here about how to clean or repair the bootloader for mac, but to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are there any external devices connected? And have you installed all the latest drivers for bootcamp?

Comment: @Lachlan, Yes there are some external HDD's connected, though they've never really made a difference before. Will try unplugging them next boot. If it's them, is there a solution, short of unplugging them every time I start up? As for updates, yes, got the latest drivers recently.

Comment: I would not have thought that external HDD would have caused the issue here but definitely try booting without them next time, it may be worth doing a file systems disk check as there mat be issues there, also reset PRAM just incase.

Comment: @Lachlan, No worries. Should I do the systems check through Mac or Windows? How should I go about it?

Comment: just boot in single user mode and do it, if you do not know how, at startup hold control + s and once in /sbin/fsck -fy should perform the check

Comment: Have you tried to boot in verbose mode ? (by pressing - and keeping pressed - `v` before the gong). You should read something unexpected...